# Using a imported module in python result in permission denied error

Tags: python, import, permissions, pip

I'm trying to use a imported module (pylightning) in a python script that runs using apache under user www-data.

The script gives a permission error when run via apache as user www-data:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/lightning/lightning.py", line 69, in call
sock.connect(self.socket_path)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

To fix this I have intensively searched and found i needed to reinstall the module as www-data user:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall pylightning
sudo -H -u www-data pip3 install pylightning
```

The script still runs smoothly from the CLI as regular user:

```
$python3 index.py
Content-Type: text/html


<html><body>
etc...
```

But from apache (through a browser or from the command line as user www-data) still gives the same error:

```
$sudo -u www-data python3 /var/www/html/index.py
Content-Type: text/html


<html><body>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/www/html/index.py", line 29, in <module>
print(rpc_interface.listpeers())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/lightning/lightning.py", line 345, in listpeers
return self.call("listpeers", payload)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/lightning/lightning.py", line 69, in call
sock.connect(self.socket_path)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Anyone has any idea here?

Script source:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import hashlib
from lightning.lightning import LightningRpc

rpc_interface = LightningRpc("/home/pi/.lightning/lightning-rpc")
print ("Content-Type: text/html\n\n");
print ("</body></html>asd");
print(rpc_interface.listpeers())
```

the error triggers on this line: 
    print(rpc_interface.listpeers())

Comment: Do you know what port number it is trying to use?

Comment: no, unfortunately not. I can't find that information in the documentation/code and don't know how to obtain it from my system.

Comment: Does the www-data user have permission to access `/home/pi/.lightning/lightning-rpc` (including parent directories)?

Comment: this is from user pi. pi is in group www-data and vice versa

Comment: That's no guarantee.  That file, or any parent directories, could be owner-readable but not group-readable.

Comment: that was it!!! i found two directories lower that a group access for www-data was not granted. now it works! thanks.

Comment: how can I show my gratitude in this system?

Comment: I'll write up that comment as an answer, and you can click the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that the www-data user has permission to access `/home/pi/.lightning/lightning-rpc` (including parent directories).